# Newbie question: VHDL best practice/Efficiency

Tags: vhdl

I have recently started to teach myself VHDL. Being an embedded systems programmer the language itself and its constructs are not much of a problem. My problem is the development of the intuitive knowledge how my code is mapped onto the silicon. When I write C code for an embedded processor I have a fairly good idea how the code gets translated (compiled) and how it is run within the processor. This is what I want to develop for my VHDL authoring.
I am reading sample programs (which I found is usually not a good idea as it only shows you what can be done, not necessarily how things should be done)

I hereby present a snippet of an example program and the same snippet after my C-brain has moulded it into something which I can be better understand.

My questions are; "Does what I did translate into a more or a less efficient implementation on silicon. Did I or did I not violate best practices."

Example

```
    -- Create a delay pulse of 16us when a key is pressed
    PROCESS( clk, rst )
    BEGIN
        IF( NOT rst = '1' ) THEN
            cnt_delay <= "00000000000000000000";
            start_delaycnt <= '0';
        ELSIF( clk'EVENT AND clk='1' ) THEN
            IF( start_delaycnt = '1' ) THEN
                IF (cnt_delay /= "11000011010100000000") THEN   -- 800.000 -> cnt_delay pulse is 16us long
                    cnt_delay <= cnt_delay + "00000000000000000001";
                ELSE
                    cnt_delay <= "00000000000000000000";
                    start_delaycnt <= '0';
                END IF;
            ELSE
                IF( (NOT key_input='1') AND (cnt_delay = "00000000000000000000") ) THEN
                    start_delaycnt <= '1';
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
```

My attempt:

```
    -- Create a delay pulse of 16us when a key is pressed
    PROCESS( clk, rst )
    BEGIN
        -- in reset -> reset our output signal and reset the counter
        IF( NOT rst = '1' ) THEN
            cnt_delay <= "00000000000000000000";
            start_delaycnt <= '0';
-- Edit Fixed bug. Cannot invert EVENT attribute
--      -- No clock transition -> do nothing
--      ELSIF( NOT( clk'EVENT AND clk='1' ) ) THEN

--      -- Key pressed and not currently in a delay -> start the delay
--      ELSIF( (NOT key_input='1') AND (start_delaycnt = '0') ) THEN

        -- On positive clock edge -> do work
        ELSIF( clk'EVENT AND clk='1' ) THEN

            -- Key pressed and not currently in a delay -> start the delay
            IF( (NOT key_input='1') AND (start_delaycnt = '0') ) THEN

            start_delaycnt <= '1';

        -- If we are currently in a delay and we have not reached the end it yet -> increase the counter
        ELSIF( (start_delaycnt = '1') AND (cnt_delay /= "11000011010100000000") ) THEN  -- 800.000 -> cnt_delay pulse is 16ms long
            cnt_delay <= cnt_delay + "00000000000000000001";

        -- If we are currently in a delay and we have reached the end -> reset our output signal and reset the counter
        ELSIF( start_delaycnt = '1' ) THEN
            cnt_delay <= "00000000000000000000";
            start_delaycnt <= '0';
        END IF;

        END IF;

    END PROCESS;
```

I know a string of elsifs is not quite ideal, but as I said I am still learning VHDL and I need to get a bit better acquainted with the constructs to get rid of these eyesores. However maybe this is the most efficient/best practice way.

I am looking forward to any critique of this snippets.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read and respond.

edit: Fixed calculation mistake. The delay is 16us not 16ms.
2nd edit: Fixed bug. Cannot invert EVENT attribute.

Addendum:
This was my first question on stack overflow and I noticed that it has been down voted quite heavily. Can someone tell me what I did wrong so I can avoid it in future questions.

Ok, ok. Just read Good subjective, Bad subjective and I realise I should have posed the question somewhere else. How do I close this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think of a clocked PROCESS as a Central PROCESSing Unit. Now replace "Central" with "Distributed Parallel", i.e. akin to multiple parallel cores.

In the example you gave, the delay is implemented by counting clock cycles (800 in this case).

The conditional test IF (clk'EVENT AND clk='1') creates a positive edge detection circuit in the silicon. In this case it looks for rising edges of the clk signal. Then you need to decide what to do on those rising edges to implement your clocked process.

Note: Negative edge detection is implemented by IF (clk'EVENT AND clk='0')

Comment: Yes, I understand the semantics. The question was not so much aimed at what it does but how it is synthesized to silicon. Would the synthesizer create the same logic for both snippets or not.
Is the way I crafted the example frowned upon or not.

Basically I am trying to create a programming style and want that to allign with industry practices.

Comment: This code is counting 800.000 clock cycles using a clock running at 50MHz, creating a 16us delay
( 50MHz / 800.000 = 62.5kHz; 1/62.5kHz = 16us ).

I want to use the positive edge of the clock, hence the clk'EVENT AND clk='1'. Traditionally you would say, At the positive edge, do this. To make the ELSIF's flow I had to invert it. Basically I am saying; if you do not have a positive edge, do nothing else do something.

Comment: A clocked process is used to implement sequential logic. Your attempt ignores the clock, so it's combinational logic instead. It does nothing on clock edges, so it won't count clock cycles.

Comment: Ah-ha. So if i understand you correctly, you can invert signal levels, but you cannot invert the EVENT attribute.

I should have synthesize my code before posting. Just did and it threw an error "statement is not synthesizable since it does not hold its value under NOT(clock-edge) condition" (embarrassing)